# Having Trouble using AJAX with jquery in Wordpress FrontEnd

Tags: ajax, wordpress

Hello I am developing a plugin for Word Press,
Admin area is all ok but i want to use AJAX in front end to send some data to my server.
I am using AJAX in jquery like

jQuery.AJAX({
My code.....
})

But its not working, As the same code approach working well at admin side.
the file where I post my data is in my plugin directory
I am attaching the code  please check what am i doing wrong thanks

This is the front end file

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
         
           var url= jQuery('#url').val();
            jQuery.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                URL:url,
                data:{
                    data:'azam'
                },
                success:function(data)
                {
 
                }
 
            })
 
        });
```

Here is my php file

```
function hello($a)
{
    $a = $_POST['data'];
    echo $a;

}
add_action('wp_ajax_hello', 'hello');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_hello', 'hello');
```

Please dont give me online links caz i search whole internet already but i cant understand how it works. please help

Comment: Did you debug, the problem, its from client side(ajax side) or server side (php side) ? Request is sending on server or not ?

Comment: data:'action=hello' and add die();  in hello function

Comment: are you using `wp_localize_script` ? And can you add the code where you are enqueuing script?

Comment: i cant enque any script i write this script under my html in <script> tags

Comment: and i dont know where to localize the script its a mess plz guide me

Comment: function ajaxurl() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var AjaxUrl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
</script>
<?php
}
add_action('wp_head','ajaxurl'); you need to add action parameter into your data

    .ajax({
        type:"POST",
        URL:AjaxUrl, // is this url correct? it should be admin ajax url
        data:{
            action:'hello',
            data:'azam'
        },

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks mostly correct but here are my findings:

1. In the end of your hello function add die();
2. Are you using correct admin ajax url?

add this to your functions.php to output admin ajax url.

```
function ajaxurl() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var AjaxUrl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
</script>
<?php
}

add_action('wp_head','ajaxurl');
```

3. you need to add action parameter into your data

   ```
       .ajax({
           type:"POST",
           URL:AjaxUrl, // is this url correct? it should be admin ajax url
           data:{
               action:'hello',
               data:'azam'
           },
   ```

Comment: how to add action parameter?? please explain

Comment: why the url should be admin ajax url?? as I write my php code somewhere else

Comment: data parameter should contain it. I have shown it in the code. In your case if the ajax function name is hello than action parameter should be 'hello'

Comment: You need admin ajax url to use ajax in Wordpress. That is the best practice for using ajax in wordpress and besides very convenient way once you get the idea. Basically with add_action('wp_ajax_hello', 'hello');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_hello', 'hello'); you are registering your function into a list of wordpress ajax functions and then you send ajax request to admin ajax url and indicate in action parameter which of registered functions should be used.

Comment: u means to say that if i need to save data in database then i write code in function.php file not somewhere else
am i right?

Comment: yes, that is correct and try using wpdb for working with database. It is also wordpress way of doing things :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112030/discussion-between---and-nick-surmanidze).

Answer (score 0):

If u use wp_enqueue_script, i suggest u to add this function in your main php file.

```
function plugin_ajax_articles()
{
   wp_enqueue_script( "your_js_file", get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/your_js_file.js', array('jquery'), "1.0.0", true );

   wp_localize_script( 'your_js_file', 'url', admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) );
}
add_action("init", "plugin_ajax_articles");
```

Then in ur js file, URl will work.
Don't forget to add a "die();" at the end of your php function.

If u have time, read this article => [Tuto Ajax WordPress](http://nozifel.fr/didacticiels/categories/single/wordpress-et-les-requetes-ajax/)

I hope that help u :)

Comment: the function load_articles  where to write definition of this function??? in admin-ajax file???